# Undefined variable: missing in

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm currently trying to figure out PHP. however I keep running into some errors.

this is my PHP line of code that has two errors:
1)Undefined variable: missing
2)in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array
my best guess would be the missing variable ($missing) would be missing however I defined it just above it. 
the errors are in the line: if (!in_array($email, $missing))

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $expected)) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $value = trim($value);
        }

        if (empty($value) && in_array($key,$required)) {
            $$key = '';
            $missing[] = $key;
        } else {
            $$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

if (!in_array($email, $missing)) {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!$email){
        $errors['email'] = 'use a valid mail address';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's expecting the second parameter, $missing, to be an array. First use, print_r to print out $missing to see what it outputs.

Comment: Your code does not guarantee that missing is going to be set. Add `$missing = array();` Before foreach.

Comment: you have got $missing[] inside if but what happens if it goes right into else?

Answer (score 0):

```
1)Undefined variable: missing
```

Yes, you've defined it, but only in one branch of the code. You don't guarantee its existence. There's obviously a situation when your variable isn't defined at all and you need to take care of it before trying to use it somewhere.

```
2)in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array
```

As the error says, you need to make 100% sure that your second parameter is indeed an array AND is defined.